# sumproduct function in apache poi (version 3.15) with if condition is not working

Tags: apache, excel-formula, sum, apache-poi, product

I'm using below formula to calculate sum product with if condition using Apache poi 3.15 version, but it's not evaluating with if condition (--(A1:A6="A")) and its giving "#VALUE" error.
The same formula if i use directly in excel, its working as expected. and if I remove "--(A1:A6="A")" this condition, it works fine with poi.

Formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A6="A"),B1:B6,C1:C6)
```

Could you please tell me how to evaluate this kind of formula or is there any alternative way to evaluate this?

Comment: Is the method you are trying to make work `setCellFormula()`? Could I perhaps see some code for perspective please?

Comment: Yes, I'm using setcellFormula() and setCellType(). At last I'm evaluating the workbook.          setcellFormula("SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A6="A"),B1:B6,C1:C6)");                        setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);                                         FormulaEvaluatorgetCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator(); valuator.evaluateAll();

Answer (score 0):

Okay, sorry for originally barking up the wrong tree...

A fresh pair of Monday eyes and I can see the issue:

You are using quotes `"` inside a quoted string, you need to escape the quotes in the formula with `\` - `cell.setCellFormula("SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A6=\"A\"),B1:B6,C1:C6)");`

<strike>`=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A6="A")*(B1:B6)*(C1:C6))` **- Edited to desired logic**</strike>

By using the double unary "`--`" you convert true/false in to 0 or 1.

This is an if condition, so you need to also multiple each row of data by the 0 or 1 and sum the result; when the condition is false the product of the row will multiply by 0 giving a total of 0 to be summed for that row.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A6="A"),B1:B6,C1:C6) formula is returning "#VALUE" error with poi. if I use the same formula directly in excel, its working as expected. SUMPRODUCT logic = a1*b1+a2*b2. I want to achieve this logic with if condition

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look at converting this to base `SUM(IF())` but can you clarify exactly what you would like because `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A6="A"),B1:B6,C1:C6)` in excel provides the logic `=A1*B1*C1+A2*B2*C2` whereas `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A6="A")*(B1:B6+C1:C6))` provides the logic `=(A1*(B1+C1))+(A2*(B2+C2))` the logic you provided doesn't match either and I'd need to know for sure before going ahead.

Comment: Logic i'm expecting is = b1*c1+b2*c2  using sumproduct function with if condition

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the formula, it's with the workbook which I'm using. The workbook SXSSFWorkbook has an issue with evaluation. When I changed to XSSFWorkbook, it started evaluating properly.

I suggest using either XSSFWorkbook(.xlsx) or HSSFWorkbook(.xls) in order to make the formula work properly.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B6,C1:C6,--(A1:A6="A"))
```

Note: Do not put IF condition (--(A1:A6="A")) as first argument.

Thanks